# Is there a way of inserting an id into a Thymeleaf variable dynamically?

Tags: java, servlets, thymeleaf, httpsession

I have added some Http session variables in a Java class inside a loop, and each session variable contains a unique identifier as part of it's name.

I want to be able to read these variables from a loop on a Thymeleaf template, using the identifier which was set for each. Is this possible? And if so what syntax should I use to insert the id to the name of my session variable in the Thymeleaf template?

The name of each Http session variable is "Sid"+unique_id, as below.

```
    <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
                            <td th:text="${item.id}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${item.name}"></td>
                            <td th:if="${item.expired != null 
                            and session.Sid${item.id} == 'available'}">
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).

```
<tr th:each="item : ${items}">
    <td th:text="${item.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${item.name}"></td>
    <td th:if="${item.expired != null and session.Sid__${item.id}__ == 'available'}">??<td>
</tr>
```

(It works, but in general I wouldn't recommend this kind of structure.  I think you should be using a map, or some other data structure built for pulling out data like this.  Then you could do something like: `session.sids[item.id]` or `session.sids.get(item.id)`)

Comment: Thank you very much! Out of curiosity, why would you not recommend this approach?

Comment: @James it makes your code more fragile.  Imagine if item.id ever contained a space (or somehow happened to be negative).  You would get thymeleaf parser errors, and the page itself would be unusable.  If you were using a map, or other data structure the page would render as normal (because session.sids[item.id] would just return null).